# How to return Javascript as partial response?

Tags: javascript, jsf-2

As response to an Ajax-request I want to return Javascript that is executed on the client immediately.
I tried it like this but it doesn't work:

```
<html xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
<h:head></h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <h:commandButton value="js">
            <f:ajax event="click" listener="#{myBean.js}"/>
        </h:commandButton>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

the bean:

```
package mypackage;

import javax.faces.context.ExternalContext;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.context.PartialResponseWriter;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named
public class MyBean {

    public void js() {
        System.out.println("called");
        FacesContext ctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        ExternalContext extContext = ctx.getExternalContext();
        if (ctx.getPartialViewContext().isAjaxRequest()) {
            try {
                extContext.setResponseContentType("text/xml");
                extContext.addResponseHeader("Cache - Control ", "no - cache");
                PartialResponseWriter writer = ctx.getPartialViewContext()
                        .getPartialResponseWriter();
                writer.startDocument();
                writer.startEval();
                writer.write("alert(’Works!’);");
                writer.endEval();
                writer.endDocument();
                writer.flush();
                ctx.responseComplete();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The response will be Javascript text. you need to pass it thru, eval to evaluate it.

but that will be dangerous, why dont u just get plain data from json and do something based on that and keep the java script in the client ?

Comment: @Amogh: It's only dangerous if it contains inlined user-controlled input. Currently, it's just hardcoded in the server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
writer.write("alert(’Works!’);");
```

Curly quotes are not a valid string delimiter in JS. Use straight quotes.

```
writer.write("alert('Works!');");
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, based on your question history you're using PrimeFaces, or at least familiar with it. In that case, just use [`RequestContext#execute()`](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/3.5/org/primefaces/context/RequestContext.html#execute%28java.lang.String%29) instead of this mess.