# How would I call a JavaScript function from a JSF Bean?

Tags: javascript, jsf

I need to do this from Java code, I was trying the following, but got stuck:

```
    UIOutput js = new UIOutput();
    js.setRendererType("javax.faces.resource.Script");
    js.getAttributes().put("library", "js");
    js.setValue("alert(123);");

    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    context.getViewRoot().addComponentResource(context, js, "body");
```

I didn't get an error with this in the server log, but also didn't see the alert.

Any idea?

**EDIT:** I tried the suggested solution, the alleged duplicate, and I didn't get a server error either, but neither did I see any alert..

Comment: Why do you create components using Java code?

Comment: @Tiny because he tried to create something that would dynamically run a script

Comment: possible duplicate of [Initiating JavaScript call from server side](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28969157/initiating-javascript-call-from-server-side)

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you want to do this from a JSF ManagedBean, not a JSF Component.

I'm not sure there is a 'plain' jsf solution for this (meaning not adding another framework or creating and maintaining some specific java code).

There are at least 2 solutions (the ones I worked with):

- [`Ajax.onComplete("alert('Hi'')")`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/utils/Ajax) from the [OmniFaces utility framework](http://omnifaces.org/)
- [RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("alert('Hi'')")](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/requestContext.xhtml) from [PrimeFaces](http://www.primefaces.org)

I'm sure all other component suites (RichFaces, IceFaces, OpenFaces, ...) have some similar solution.

If you want to stay using plain JSF, I'd go for using OmniFaces. It's a great addition in general and prevents you from maintaining knowledge about implementation specifics.

Edit: I just found a [plain jsf solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17864326/how-to-return-javascript-as-partial-response)

Comment: Thanks! Actually I'm using RichFaces, I will google for something similar there!

Comment: There doesn't seem to be something similar in RichFaces, do you know anything?

Comment: I tried that, but I'm getting an `JSF AJAX Error:
description: "An empty response was received from the server.  Check server error logs.", responseCode: 200, responseText: "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>↵<partial-response><changes><eval><![CDATA[alert(123);]]></eval>", responseXML: null` and I don't see the alert

Comment: Then I think  your richfaces ajax response  handler does not seem to support this  and I'm out of suggestions.

Comment: Although, you could try to add a dummy update to 'satisfy' the ajax response handler and parse the response yourself and 'eval' the javascript part

Comment: Thanks. I also need the RichFaces response part though to avoid breaking the application.

Answer (score -1):

Please try this:

```
JavaScriptRunner.runScript(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), "alert(hello)");
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know my version. But I tried the follows and it works in my environment

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getResponseWriter().write("<script>alter('hello');</script>");
```