# How would I call a JavaScript function from a JSF Bean using RichFaces?

Tags: javascript, jsf, richfaces

For example in PrimeFaces there is

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("alert(123)")
```

And in OmniFaces there is

```
Ajax.onComplete("alert(123)")
```

I tried the pure JSF options I got from:

- [How would I call a JavaScript function from a JSF Bean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29392000/how-would-i-call-a-javascript-function-from-a-jsf-bean)
- [Initiating JavaScript call from server side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28969157/initiating-javascript-call-from-server-side)
- [How to return Javascript as partial response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17864326/how-to-return-javascript-as-partial-response)

but neither of them works with Richfaces, specifically I'm either getting **no** alert in the response (using the first two options), or (using the last option) **only** the alert and an otherwise empty response with the follwing error in the browser console:

```
JSF AJAX Error:
description: "An empty response was received from the server. Check server error logs.",
responseCode: 200,
responseText: "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>?<partial-response><changes><eval><![CDATA[alert(123);]]></eva??l>",
responseXML: null
```

How can I just pass some JavaScript to the browser from Java code using RichFaces?

Thanks

Comment: What version of JSF are you using? Depending on the version, you can take advantage of newer response writing libs and just write your script directly to the ajax response

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to directly call JavaScript from a bean?

RichFaces components have `@oncomplete`, it lets you set code to be executed when the request comes back from the server.

Comment: Thanks, but yeah I really need this here from within a controller, not component specific. Isn't there some equivalent to `RequestContext#getCurrentInstance()#execute()` or some hack?

Comment: Well, the controller is still responding to a request from the page, isn't it? Anyway concerning the "empty response" error, that's not from RichFaces, by the looks of it the response you're creating is invalid XML. (</eva??l>, doesn't look good.) I've tried it and it works fine.

Comment: Oh can you please show me the code you were using? I tried the code suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17864326/how-to-return-javascript-as-partial-response which uses eval and caused the invalid response

Comment: I tried it again with the quotes fixed, but when I keep the `writer.endDocument(); writer.flush();` I don't get the entire response as expected by RichFaces (I don't execute this on a `h:commandButton` click but in the controller code during another request) and when I omit the  `writer.endDocument(); writer.flush();` I doesn't get insertert correctly into `<partialresponse>` tag but just prepended **before** the `<?xml ..`  start of the response. In both cases I'm getting an erroneous response